# jquery issue copying data from div to input text

Tags: jquery, in-place

I am working on inplace edit for a form. 
I am having two divs one of them holds display elements and the other holds input form.

When you click edit data moves from display div to input form. I see the change when I use val(text), however when I serialize the form to json elements are old.

I need some help understanding what is the problem here?

Here is some code:

```
function editForm2(){
    $("#editLink").click(function() {
        if (this.text == 'Edit') {
            console.log('editing');
            $("#display div.edit").each(function(i) {
                var e = $("#input :input")[i];
                $(e).val($(this).text());
            });
            $("#display").hide();
            $("#input").show();
            $(this).text('Save');
        }
        else if (this.text =='Save') {
            // problem is here... When I serialize the form I got nothing ?!
            console.log('saving');
            console.log($("#form1 :input")); // old values

            var json_form = $('#form1').serializeObject();
            console.log(json_form); // old values?
            $(this).text('Edit');

            $("#display").show();
            $("#input").hide();
        }
    });

    console.log(this);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    editForm2();
});​
```

here is html

```
<div class="editSection" id="display" >
    <div id="person_firstName" class="edit" width="200">
        Hello
    </div>
    <div id="person_lastName" class="edit">
        World
    </div>
</div>

<div class="editSectionEdit" id="input" >
    <form id="form1">
        <input name="person_firstName_in" type="text" class="edit" value="123" >
        <input name="person_lastName_in" type="text" class="edit" value="456" >
    </form>
</div><br/>

<div id="buttons">
    <a href="#" id="editLink">Edit</a>
    <a href="#" id="cancelLink">Cancel</a>
</div><br>

<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Could you post only relevant codes?

Comment: Cleaned up. Basically when you click editLink button it will change from edit to save and vice versa. Depends on text of the field it will copy data from div to input elements, my problem is in save portion of the code when form is serialized the val() for input doesn't persist?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `.serializeObject()` which was reported as undefined by firebug.

Here is your solution

```
var json_form = $('#form1').serialize();
```

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/hBC39/)